# Как найти сумму всех элементов в объекте JS?

Tags: javascript, объекты

```
let obj = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 65,
  salary: 5000,
  number: 5,
}
```

Мне нужно чтобы в ответе была сумма всех элементов объекта, то есть 5070.

Я пытался решить, но у меня ничего не получилось. Вот мой код:

```
let sum = 0;
for (let key in obj) {
  sum += obj[key];
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 65,
  salary: 5000,
  number: 5,
}

let sum = 0;
for (let key in obj) {
  if (typeof obj[key] === 'number')
    sum += obj[key];
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Есть еще вариант: `Object.values(obj).filter(function(v) { return typeof v === 'number'; }).reduce(function(x, y) { return x + y; });`